# How to get the thumbnail of a recorded video - windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, thumbnails, video-capture

I've used `CaptureSource()` to record a video like in this Topic [How to record video in a camera app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394041%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but I can't get the thumbnail of the recorded video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

[...]

```
// Add eventhandlers for captureSource.
captureSource.CaptureFailed += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(OnCaptureFailed);
captureSource.CaptureImageCompleted += captureSource_CaptureImageCompleted;
```

[...]

```
captureSource.Start();
captureSource.CaptureImageAsync();
```

[...]

```
void captureSource_CaptureImageCompleted(object sender, CaptureImageCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
  {
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap wb = e.Result;

     string fileName = "CameraMovie.jpg";
     if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
         isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName); 

     IsolatedStorageFileStream file = isoStore.CreateFile(fileName);

     System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, file, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);

     file.Close();
 }
}
```

**UPDATE : Give the user the possibility to take the thumbnail when he want**

Add an Tap event to `viewfinderRectangle`

```
<Rectangle 
    x:Name="viewfinderRectangle"
    [...]
    Tap="viewfinderRectangle_Tap" />
```

Call `captureSource.CaptureImageAsync();` in that Tap event

```
private void viewfinderRectangle_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
 captureSource.CaptureImageAsync();
}
```

Comment: how to get the size of the video while recording is on?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to get the size of the video while recording

Comment: any ide aon how to change the resolution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715390/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-camera-while-recording-video-in-wp8

Comment: Have you seen this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662939(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I am using AudioVideoCaptureDevice. is there any way to get the thumbnail from this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. If you are using AudioVideoCaptureDevice api. following events call after every frame capture. You can choose any frame that you need. As take first one.

```
private AudioVideoCaptureDevice VideoRecordingDevice;
VideoRecordingDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable += previewThumbnail;
bool DisablePreviewFrame = false;

private void previewThumbnail(ICameraCaptureDevice a, object b)
{
    if (!DisablePreviewFrame)
    {
        DisablePreviewFrame = true;
        int frameWidth = (int)VideoRecordingDevice.PreviewResolution.Width;
        int frameHeight = (int)VideoRecordingDevice.PreviewResolution.Height;
    }
    int[] buf = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
    VideoRecordingDevice.GetPreviewBufferArgb(buf);
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStoreFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        var fileName = "temp.jpg";

        if (isoStoreFile.FileExists(fileName))
            isoStoreFile.DeleteFile(fileName);
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isostream = isoStoreFile.CreateFile(fileName))
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(frameWidth, frameWidth);
            Array.Copy(buf, wb.Pixels, buf.Length);
            wb.SaveJpeg(isostream, 120, 120, 0, 60);
            isostream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```