# How to create Thumbnail from video file(.mp4) on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: video, windows-phone-8

I've used AudioVideoCapture devise to record a video, but I can't get the thumbnail of the recorded video. Please help me!

Comment: this question is answered here

[How to get the thumbnail of a recorded video - windows phone 8][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271922/how-to-get-the-thumbnail-of-a-recorded-video-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. If you are using AudioVideoCaptureDevice api. following event(previewThumbnail) call after every frame capture. You can choose any frame that you need. As take first one.

```
private AudioVideoCaptureDevice VideoRecordingDevice;
VideoRecordingDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable += previewThumbnail;
bool DisablePreviewFrame = false;

private void previewThumbnail(ICameraCaptureDevice a, object b)
{
    if (!DisablePreviewFrame)
    {
        DisablePreviewFrame = true;
        int frameWidth = (int)VideoRecordingDevice.PreviewResolution.Width;
        int frameHeight = (int)VideoRecordingDevice.PreviewResolution.Height;
    }
    int[] buf = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
    VideoRecordingDevice.GetPreviewBufferArgb(buf);
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStoreFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        var fileName = "temp.jpg";

        if (isoStoreFile.FileExists(fileName))
            isoStoreFile.DeleteFile(fileName);
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isostream = isoStoreFile.CreateFile(fileName))
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(frameWidth, frameWidth);
            Array.Copy(buf, wb.Pixels, buf.Length);
            wb.SaveJpeg(isostream, 120, 120, 0, 60);
            isostream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```