# Video Thumbnail from http url

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Is it any possible way to create a video thumbnail from random url?
I have some links with video and I want to make a thumbnail from that video and save the thumbnail image on local storage. If any possible way to do this ?

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271922/how-to-get-the-thumbnail-of-a-recorded-video-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for youtube videos:-

```
public string GetThumbnailsUrl(string url)// this url is your youtube video url
{
    string imgurl = "";
    if (url != "")
    {
        if (!url.ToLower().Contains("embed/"))//if not an embed URL
        {
            string v = url;
            if (url.Contains("?"))
            {
                v = v.Substring(v.LastIndexOf("v=") + 2);
                if (v.Contains("&"))
                    v = v.Substring(0, v.LastIndexOf("&"));
            }
            else
            {
                v = v.Substring(v.LastIndexOf("v/") + 2);
            }
            int i = 0;
            try
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageSize"].Trim());//ImageSize contains the size of image.... the value is like 0,1,2,3.....
            }
            catch { i = 0; }

            imgurl = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + v + "/" + i + ".jpg";
        }
        else//For embed URL
        {
            string[] sep = new string[1] { "embed/" };
            string[] ss = url.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string key = ss[ss.Length - 1];
            int i = 0;
            try
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageSize"].Trim());
            }
            catch { i = 0; }
            imgurl = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + key + "/" + i + ".jpg";
        }


    }
    return imgurl;
}
```

Comment: is there any solution for non youtube video?